# How to remove hours from Scrum 2.0 template

Tags: tfs, scrum

We are currently using Scrum 2.0 process template from microsoft in new TFS 2012, however we don't use hours as task estimates, we simply count tasks. This is easily archieved by setting each task value as 1 as default and set that field read only in task property form.

However original template uses hours as unit with tasks, so there are are mark "h" all around template. Is there way to get rid of this hour mark since it causes constant confusion? Especially in management.

Comment: Do you mean from Web Access? I can't see anywhere in VS itself where the 'h' is. Can you give an example of where one of these rogue h's is?

Answer (score 4):

You can configure how the remaining work is displayed, by modifying the **format** attribute in the following row in the **commonconfiguration.xml** file:

```
<TypeField refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork" type="RemainingWork" format="{0} h" />
```

By default this attribute is "{0} h", so you can simply set it to "{0}" to fit your needs.

You can download the commonconfiguration.xml file from the server, using the **witadmin** command:

```
witadmin exportcommonprocessconfig /collection:http:<your collection> /p:<your project> /f:<the file name>
```

After editing the file you must import it back into TFS using witadmin command:

```
witadmin importcommonprocessconfig ...the same parameters as above
```

Note: with the RC it looks like you must leave a space after the placeholder, like **"{0} "**, otherwise you will get a validation error, when importing the file. I haven't tried yet with the RTM to see if this has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, all of those h's are hardcoded straight into web access. So the only way to remove them would be to find them (I used Chrome's dev tools), isolate them, and then go into the Web Access pages located on your TFS Server (application tier) and manually remove them. This is because they aren't actually part of any template, so there isn't a way to remove them all at once. The path to the files will be something like

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\Application Tier\Web Services
```

Good luck, I've had a heck of a time trying to alter them.

Comment: I would not recommend this as it would potentially leave your TFS server in an unserviceable state. At best it would be unsupported and be overwritten during an update and at worst it would fail the update and require a reinstall...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TFPT](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) or the [WITADMIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd236909.aspx) command line tool to remove the remaining effort field.

I would suggest however **not** to remove it, but rather to remove it from the form itself (so that it just doesn't show), and add a rule so that it defaults to **1** and is read-only. Furthermore, in the workflow, add a rule that changes the value to 0 when you reach **done**.

Since there's no actual meaning to the number itself, the units can be actual hours, ideal hours, story points or whatever you want them to mean. By making each task 1 or 0 (when done), you can make use of TFS' built in tools such as the burndown reports to track your progress. Each task done will reduce the remaining work, and you will be able to keep track of velocity by summing up the effort completed in each iteration (which is the same as counting).

Comment: This will not remove the "h" references from the Web Access and will instead render them as only 0's

+1 to the "there is no actual meaning": just pretend there are no "h"'s